# How to address the events of a Doc datasource passed into a Custom Control via property definition?

Tags: xpages

I'm using a property definition to pass a document datasource into a custom control.

Is there a way to bind that datasource to the page the same way as if I had defined it on the page itself?

What I'm looking for is a way to use my passed-in ds for simple data binding in controls avoiding computed EL statements. What's more important: is there a way to address the datasource's event handlers (like querySaveDocument) from inside my custom control? Or can I only address them in the page where the ds has been defined originally?

Comment: [This post from Tommy Valand can help you.](http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2010/03/xpages-dynamically-binding-document.html)

Comment: @Naveen: thanks a ton - at first glance this seems to exactly describe my  problem and its solution! I'll give it a try first thing tomorrow morning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is described in [custom control enlightenment](https://prezi.com/gubendoqbl1t/custom-controls-enlightenment/) together with some other thoughts on custom controls. Have a look and then use Tommy's library